# In xamarin forms ios Launchscreen and App icon didnt change

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, launch-screen

I changed my App icon from Assets but still didnt change. How can I fix that problem ? I read similar question and I did what they say but it didnt fixed.I also select do not display LaunchScreen and than change it again but id didnt show up still.
[On my iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No2Il.jpg)

[Assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYsgu.jpg)

[İnfo.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6o5E.jpg)

[LaunchScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqabw.jpg)

And my other questin is how can I set an image as a Launchscreen without Mac ?

Comment: You could delete the folder bin and obj , then re-install the app to check if the issue still exists .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT re-install from where ?

Comment: Delete the app from your device and deploy it again .

Comment: it didint work @LucasZhang-MSFT

Comment: You could post the issue to **Help->Send feedback->report problem** .

Comment: Right click on Assets.xcassets and delete Asset catalog. Then open info.plist as Application (tab). App Icons section click "Use Asset catalog" button. It will create new Assets.xcassets (Asset catalog). Where insert all your app icons. Should work. Pease update the result.

Comment: @Ranjit it is also didint work

Comment: @AlaraIscan not sure what issue. Did you solved?